# Are there disadvantages to using :before & :after CSS?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Before I implement these to my site, just wanted to know if someone has any negative experience using :before and :after to design. (or outweighing positive aspects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by using pseudo element, you make it more semantic. You don't need to create empty element just for layout purposes.

The cons, I believe some legacy browsers won't support it, but you can use polyfill for that.

Comment: yes, but most of the time I only put trivial things within my pseudo element. Like shadow or extra layout. In that case I can ignore those legacy browsers. If they didn't see those, they won't miss anything much..

Comment: yup, exactly. If it's important, you might want to create actual HTML element, then put ID/class in it, so you can hook it with javascript in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Say if you have a site like SO which has multple answers on each page. If you want to add an image/icon after each answer you could have something like

```
answercell.post-text:after {
    content: url(images/disclaimer.gif);
}
```

that way you can update the entire site without having to change a single HTML/ASPX page

So it makes site wide updates easier.

Addtionally it would reduce the page size in (Kb) as you would require less HTML so the page would load faster.